# how to prevent proguard obfuscation from changing the code?

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I have a problem with proguard obfuscation it changes some parts of the code and causes errors
for example I have the following code:

```
for (int i=0;i <rowsNb; i++){
    try {
        Integer.parseInt (model.getValueAt(i,0));
    catch (Exception){
        continue;
    }
    doSomething();
}
```

after obfuscation this part of code becomes like this:

```
for (int i=0;i <rowsNb; i++){
    try {
        model.getValueAt(i,0);
    catch (Exception){}
    doSomething();
}
```

it deletes the integer.parseInt() method that I use to check if the first column is an integer which is a condition to execute doSomething() without errors

and I have another problem with class names, some classes still have their original names (their names before obfuscation)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the product you're using and doesn't seems to be much you can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This question is 9 months old now, I did find a solution but I forget to post it here so I apologize for that.
- The problem with proguard is that it messes up when calling a function like Integer.parseInt() but not using its return value, so it gets rid of it and that can cause errors (depending on the code), so just use another way to test if the values is an integer or assign the return value to a variable.
- For the other question about keeping some classes original names I noticed that it only keeps the names of the classes that contain a main method, so you can rename them manually just before obfuscation.